# Remove last character of a string (VB.NET 2008)

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trying to remove a last character of a string. This last character is a newline (System.Environment.NewLine).

I have tried some things, but I can not remove it.

Example:

```
myString.Remove(sFP.Length - 1)
```

Example 2:

```
myString= Replace(myString, Environment.NewLine, "", myString.Length - 1)
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your newline is CR LF, it's actually two consecutive characters.  Try your `Remove` call with `Length - 2`.

If you want to remove all "\n" and "\r" characters at the end of string, try calling `TrimEnd`, passing the characters:

```
str.TrimEnd(vbCr, vbLf)
```

To remove all the whitespace characters (newlines, tabs, spaces, ...) just call `TrimEnd` without passing anything.

Comment: Like in C#, VB strings are immutable.

Comment: @Konrad Of course! Now that I think about it, it's actually important to point out in this question as it may be particularly confusing. To clarify, I meant to provide an *expression*, not a *statement*.  It won't modify the `str` variable. The return value is a distinct string.  You have to use something like `str = str.TrimEnd()` if you want the variable to change.

Comment: ok. thank you. Solved following your example: myString = myString.Remove(mystring.Length - 2)

Comment: @yae It's a bit unreliable though, as you may end up with a string ending with just LF and removing 2 last characters may not be what you want. `myString = myString.TrimEnd(vbCr, vbLf)` is a more reliable solution.

Comment: In many situations, just calling `TrimEnd()` or `Trim()` is a better choice.  There are a lot more white space characters than just newline, and you usually want to get rid of all of the trailing/leading whitespace.  Random fun code to see a list via reflection, tested on .Net 4: `char[] whitespace = (char[]) typeof(string).GetField("WhitespaceChars", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);`

Comment: @Brian: of course, but you may actually *want* the spaces and just need to get rid of newlines.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim str As String = "Test" & vbCrLf
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - vbCrLf.Length)
```

the same with Environment.NewLine instead of vbCrlf:

```
str = "Test" & Environment.NewLine
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length)
```

Btw, the difference is: Environment.NewLine is platform-specific(f.e. returns other string in other OS)

Your `remove`-approach didn't work because you didn't assign the return value of this function to your original string reference:

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length)
```

or if you want to replace all NewLines:

```
str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Dim str As String
str = "cars,cars,cars"
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(","))
```